# Grab JSON for Twitter users photos

Tags: php, xml, json, twitter

Twitter has now rolled out a feature for a user, whereby they display the users photos in a gallery. I've looked around the Developer Docs and cant spot any way to grab the images as a feed (json/xml). Does anyone know if there is a way to do this with PHP?

URL for everyone's reference: http://twitter.com/#!/mashable/media/grid

Comment: could you please add the url for the photo section, I kinda didn't notice this new function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1219